# Reading an InputStream into a Data object

Tags: swift, stream, inputstream, binary-data

In Swift 3.x, we usually handle binary data using `Data`; from it you can generate most other important types, and there are useful functions on it.

But how do I create a `Data` from an `InputStream`? Is there a nice way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I could not find a nice way. We can create a nice-ish wrapper around the unsafe stuff:

```
extension Data {
    init(reading input: InputStream) throws {
        self.init()
        input.open()
        defer {
            input.close()
        }

        let bufferSize = 1024
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
        defer {
            buffer.deallocate()
        }
        while input.hasBytesAvailable {
            let read = input.read(buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
            if read < 0 {
                //Stream error occured
                throw input.streamError!
            } else if read == 0 {
                //EOF
                break
            }
            self.append(buffer, count: read)
        }
    }
}
```

This is for Swift 5. Find full code with test (and a variant that reads only some of the stream) [here](https://gist.github.com/reitzig/29d38b948812454a8dedc00a9f61f44f).

Comment: good use of the defer statement.

Answer (score 1):

above the code, It can be infinite loop.
When I convert httpbodyInpustream to data, it happend.
So I add a condition.

```
extension Data {
    init(reading input: InputStream) {
        self.init()
        input.open()

        let bufferSize = 1024
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
        while input.hasBytesAvailable {
            let read = input.read(buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
            if (read == 0) {
                break  // added
            }
            self.append(buffer, count: read)
        }
        buffer.deallocate(capacity: bufferSize)

        input.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like that stream is broken; `hasBytesAvailable` should return `false`, shouldn't it? Not sure what the semantics of `hasBytesAvailable == true` but `read == 0` is; sounds like an error scenario to me.

Comment: @Raphael `InputStream.read(_ buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, maxLength len: Int) -> Int` returns `-1` if there was an error, `0` if there's no more to read, and `>1` if there are bytes left to read.

Comment: hasBytesAvailable is allowed to return true if a read has to be performed to actually check whether bytes are available (read the NSInputStream documentation). A proper implementation has to check the read result code. I modified the accepted answer with correct error handling.