# Test request body with OHHTTPStubs in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ohhttpstubs

I'm trying to test the request body sent captured with OHHTTPStubs but it seems buggy returning because the 
                `request.httpBody`  is `nil`.

I found this info about this problem [Testing for the request body in your stubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs/wiki/Testing-for-the-request-body-in-your-stubs). But I'm pretty new in iOS development and don't know how to access to `OHHTTPStubs_HTTPBody` in Swift. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess rough equivalent in Swift will be following:

```swift
import OHHTTPStubs.NSURLRequest_HTTPBodyTesting
...
stub(isMethodPOST() && testBody()) { _ in
  return OHHTTPStubsResponse(data: validLoginResponseData, statusCode:200, headers:nil)
}).name = "login"

public func testBody() -> OHHTTPStubsTestBlock {
  return { req in 
    let body = req.ohhttpStubs_HTTPBody()
    let bodyString = String.init(data: body, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

    return bodyString == "user=foo&password=bar"
  }
}
```

So, more precisely, you can access `OHHTTPStubs_HTTPBody` by calling `ohhttpStubs_HTTPBody()` method inside `OHHTTPStubsTestBlock`.

Comment: Since Swift 3 there is a small difference as request is URLRequest and the extension of OHHTTPSubs has been written for NSURLRequest. That means you need to typecast your request object first: 
`let nsRequest = request as NSURLRequest` and then you can use `nsRequest.ohhttpStubs_HTTPBody()`

Comment: @JanBrinker FYI It seems they have made an update so you don't need to cast anymore. It is available on `URLRequest` as a property: `ohhttpStubs_httpBody` so you can just do `let body = req.ohhttpStubs_httpBody`

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is the following:

```
func testYourStuff() {

    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    stub(condition: isScheme(https)) { request in
        if request.url!.host == "blah.com" && request.url!.path == "/blah/stuff" {

            let data = Data(reading: request.httpBodyStream!)
            let dict = Support.dataToDict(with: data)

            // at this point of time you have your data to test
            // for example dictionary as I have
            XCTAssertTrue(...)

        } else {
            XCTFail()
        }

        // flag that we got inside of this block
        semaphore.signal()

        return OHHTTPStubsResponse(jsonObject: [:], statusCode:200, headers:nil)
    }

    // this code will be executed first,
    // but we still need to wait till our stub code will be completed
    CODE to make https request

    _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
}

// convert InputStream to Data
extension Data {

init(reading input: InputStream) {

    self.init()
    input.open()

    let bufferSize = 1024
    let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
    while input.hasBytesAvailable {
        let read = input.read(buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
        self.append(buffer, count: read)
    }
    buffer.deallocate(capacity: bufferSize)

    input.close()
  }
}
```

Credits to this person for converting InputStrem to Data: [Reading an InputStream into a Data object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561020/reading-an-inputstream-into-a-data-object)